# What is the difference between DialCallStatus and CallStatus?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

What is the difference between **DialCallStatus** and **CallStatus**?
I saw when you use *Dial* verb with the action attribute, we can get the *DialCallStatus* and the *CallStatus*, what is the differences between these values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

DialCallStatus tells you the status of the call intiated by Twilio when you use the `<Dial>` verb and will only be included as as an HTTP parameter when Twilio requests the URL you have specified in the `<Dial>` verbs *action* attribute.

So for example, if you make a phone call into a Twilio number you can see what the CallStatus for that particular call is.  Once that call connects, if you then use the `<Dial>` verb to have Twilio make a outbound phone call and bridge it to the first call that second call has its own status, which is communicated to you using the DialCallStatus parameter.  This is because when the second call ends, the first call can continue on if you tell it to.

Does that make sense?

Hope that helps.